# Bash Array + MySQL Scripting Issue

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash

Right now I'm working on writing a short bash one-liner that grabs all the databases of the user and stores them in an array

Then grabs all of the tables for each of the databases in the array, and stores them in another array.

Then grabs all of the column names (just main ones) for each table and stores them in an array.

Eventually the final goal is to grab all of the databases, tables, and columns, and then add indexing to each of the columns.  I know how to create the index, but the array / scripting before hand to gather all of the information is where I am struggling.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

What I have so far:

```
kiradnz@ [~/public_html/blog]# 

user=$(pwd|awk -F/ '{print $3}'); 

dblist=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES like '${user}_%' ");

for word in ${dblist}; do dbARRAY+=(${word});done; 

tbls=$(for dbname in ${dblist}; do mysql $dbname -B --disable-column-names -e "show tables";done); 

for word in $tbls; do tblARRAY+=(${word});done; 

for word in ${tblARRAY[@]}; do colARRAY+=($(mysql ${dbARRAY[1]} -B --disable-column-names -e "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$word' "));done
```

What the output of this gives is the following:

```
kiradnz@mmoholic.com [~/public_html/blog]# echo ${colARRAY[@]}  

            meta_id comment_id meta_key meta_value comment_ID comment_post_ID comment_author comment_author_email comment_author_url comment_author_IP comment_date comment_date_gmt comment_content comment_karma comment_approved comment_agent comment_type comment_parent user_id link_id link_url link_name link_image link_target link_description link_visible link_owner link_rating link_updated link_rel link_notes link_rss option_id option_name option_value autoload meta_id post_id meta_key meta_value ID post_author post_date post_date_gmt post_content post_title post_excerpt post_status comment_status ping_status post_password post_name to_ping pinged post_modified post_modified_gmt post_content_filtered post_parent guid menu_order post_type post_mime_type comment_count object_id term_taxonomy_id term_order term_taxonomy_id term_id taxonomy description parent count term_id name slug term_group umeta_id user_id meta_key meta_value ID user_login user_pass user_nicename user_email user_url user_registered user_activation_key user_status display_name
```

However there are many more columns that don't get stored in the array for some reason and I'm not sure why, I have a feeling it has to do with the for loop?  Any insight?

Thanks,

Mel

Comment: Can you please edit your code so that it is a little more readable?

Comment: Tried editing it for you.  Sorry!

Comment: Just tried it here and it works perfectly for me. Have you tried some debugging statements in there? Dump out the value of $tbls before using it, for example. Make sure it has everything you want in there.

Comment: It works, with no errors, but it doesn't give add every column name to the array: colARRAY() it only adds about 1/4th of them for some reason.

Comment: how many characters in your colArray() that is only 1/4 of actual list? How many words in colArray()? Good luck.

Comment: If I simply run:

for i in $tbls; do mysql ${dbARRAY[1]} -B --disable-column-names -e "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$word' ";done

It lists around 100-150 columns, however doing it the way I mentioned only returns up to 40-50 for some reason.  I think it has to do with the for loop into the array?